# Apache2 certificate with Certbot without DNS

Tags: dns, certificate, apache2, certbot

I'm trying to setup https with apache2 and certbot. I'm using certbot for create a certificate, but when I'm using it I'm receiving this error:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following errors were reported by the server:

  Domain: www.nowbikesistemi.com
  Type:   dns
  Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
  www.nowbikesistemi.com - check that a DNS record exists for this
  domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for
  www.nowbikesistemi.com - check that a DNS record exists for this
  domain
```

This is my 000-default.conf of apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.nowbikesistemi.com
    ServerAlias www.nowbikesistemi.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know how it works on apache2, so anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I should do?

Comment: Your problem is not related to Apache, but your DNS configuration so you need to go back to your DNS provider for help. Besides, your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: But what should I do exactly?

Comment: 1) Normally, you should create a certificate for both **nowbikesistemi.com** and **www.nowbikesistemi.com**. 2) Create a DNS resource record type A for each domain name with the value being the IP address (IPv4) of your server. 3) You can also create type AAAA with the IPv6 address of your server (if supported). 4) How depends on your DNS server vendor but they are very similar with their GUI interfaces.